# Error on XIRR function of PowerBI ('Values' and 'Dates' arguments are empty)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, xirr

I'm facing a huge issue with PowerBI XIRR function. All my table lines/columns are filled with correct data, but the function returns the following error: "Unable to determine a result for XIRR because the 'Values' and 'Dates' arguments are empty."
I have 5 columns in the table: 'Dates', 'Values', 'Group1', 'Subgroup1' and 'Supplier'.
On the dashboard I have a filter of 'Date', that comes from a calendar table, that is related to the column 'Dates'. (I use this filter on all dashboards and have never had problems with it).
On the result table, I use the columns  'Group1', 'Subgroup1' and 'Supplier' to segment the 'results'.
There is one way to make the XIRR function work: adding a filter of 'Supplier' in the same dashboard. However, the function just works if I select the suppliers one-by-one. If I use the 'select all' button, the function returns the error former described.

I have already tried to use 'ALLEXCEPT' and 'ALL' filters into a CALCULATE function, but nothing solves the error.
If I use the 'ALLEXCEPT' filter, the function works, but ignores the filter of date, even if I add the 'Dates' column as a exception. If I then add a condition to not ignore 'Dates', it returns the error described above.
If I use the same filters in a CALCULATE function and use the SUM function instead of XIRR function, there is no error.
I have already removed all the table relations and applied a filter of date that's based on the 'Dates' column (one of the 5 columns from my data table), but I had the same error.

Anyone knows why it occurs and how to solve it?